# Is a screenshot of booking.com acceptable for proof of accomodation?

Tags: borders, accommodation, booking.com

I am  planning to stay in the UK for 4 months after virus; I will need to show proof of accommodation to the immigration officer.
What are accepted methods to provide proof of accommodation? Can I use a screenshot of my work phone?
How many days of accommodations do i usually need to prove?
If I will be couchsurfing for 80 percent of my stay in the UK, how should I present it to the immigration officer?

Comment: Assuming you are eligible to enter visa-free, if you’re planning on a long visit like 4 months, it’s probably more important to demonstrate that you have sufficient means to pay for your accommodation rather than show that you have something booked for the entire trip. Read this https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/827480/Visit-guidance-v9.0ext.pdf and this https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents/guide-to-supporting-documents-visiting-the-uk

Comment: Please focus on one question at a time. Pick one question here, and ask any follow-ups as separate questions.

Comment: @AndrewRay In this case I would be a bit annoyed to see three separate questions, because there is a huge overlap.

Comment: @Never Exisbut IMHO ‘after the virus’ is such an indeterminate point in time at the moment it’s almost worthless debating your question until it’s known whether eg couch-surfing will even be allowed once travel opens up again.

Comment: Each of your four questions has the same answer:
"It depends on (1) what country you come from; (2) what country your passport is from; (3) which Border Force person you encounter; (4) probably other factors."

Answer (score 7):

Booking.com provides printable booking confirmations which, once printed, look much more trustworthy than a screenshot. I always carry these when I go abroad.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't depend on being able to show a screenshot stored on your phone, things can go wrong (phone dies, etc.). You should always print these booking confirmations from the website you booked on.

There's no single answer to the next part of your question, and really depends on the discretion on the officer. If you have some accommodation booked, show proof of it. You'll also need some bank statements (again, printed) and/or credit cards with you to show you will have sufficient funds for the duration of your stay and explain you'll be couchsurfing.