# How much money is the minimum do i need for bank statement, visit the uk for 4 months

Tags: paperwork

yoooo guys, im eric from taiwan, and i am planning to continue my nomad life in the uk after virus( hopefully), since i am a low budget traveler with no income right now, but i have 7000us dollars in my bank account right now, is that enough to be acceptable by officer??
Q2: ive done some research and some information point out that its better if i could have receive money from work or from people montly, meaning "  i have stable money resource" , i could transfer my other bank account to my main account every month 300us dollars, could this work??

thank you so much guys:))

Comment: Its not about the quantity, its about the history - see the linked question for much more detail.

Comment: There is no amount of money you must show. You must have enough money - and be able to show that you understand how much money you need for your proposed itinerary.

Comment: Transferring money between your own accounts won't help and could be perceived as an attempt to 'game' the system. UK immigration are looking for a stable income from a job or something similar. FWIW I'd think that $7000 won't be enough to fund a four month stay unless you have exceptionally cheap accommodation. Don't forget that you can't work on visa-free access.

Comment: Also, planning to spend your entire life savings on a trip to the UK will make immigration officers suspect that you at least intend to work in the UK, if not overstay and settle their permanently.

Comment: Similar question asked yesterday https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/157042/is-a-screenshot-of-booking-com-acceptable-for-proof-of-accomodation